# preventing text to be clipped and append to next row if clipped in table layout in android

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am implementing TableLayout dynamically. It consists of multiple TextView. As I am adding TextView on TableRow dynamically they are getting clipped to screen boundaries. As per requirement, need to append the clipped text to next TableRow. Here is my code. Needs help..

private void init() {

```
    arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add("Name");
    arrayList.add("Address");
    arrayList.add("obj");
    arrayList.add("age");
    TableLayout.LayoutParams params = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.1f);
    TableLayout rl = (TableLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++)
    { 
        tr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++){
            tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setOnTouchListener(this);
            tv.setText(arrayList.get(j).toString());
            Log.e("text", tv.getText().toString());
            tr.addView(tv);
            tv.setPadding(5, 5, 0, 0);

            tr.setId(i);
        }
        tr.setPadding(0, 1, 0, 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `setSingleLine(false)` on your TextView.  That way it will word wrap if needed and take up more vertical space.

Comment: Thanks. But how could I get last added TextView and set this property for it? Don't understand

Comment: Set it when you create it on all of the fields.  It will only become multi-line if the space is needed.